# How do I use the Drupal 7 API to change ownership of a comment

Tags: comments

This function [`function node_assign_owner_action()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_assign_owner_action/7) is provided by the Drupal 7 API to allow modules change node ownership,

I've searched, but not found a similar function that let me change the ownership of comments. Does anyone know how to change ownership of a comment without hacking the `{comment}` table directly, and without breaking existing incoming links?

I know that I can update the fields `{comment}.uid`, `{comment}.name` and `{comment}.mail` with the appropriate values, but as I understand things, contributed modules should *never* update tables "owned" by another module directly.

The only method I've found so far is to recreate the comment under new ownership.  This is *not* a good solutions because it will invalidate all incoming links that used the permalink associated with the original comment.

Comment: One check this:https://drupal.org/files/issues/drush_extras.933030.patch also, however it is doing the same as you have mentioned.

Comment: `comment.api.php` simply dies not have a function to do it. I wonder if it could be handled ore generally, with entity-related functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This changes the comment author details using the core comment API:

```
$cid = 12; // e.g get from db_select
$comment = comment_load($cid);
$comment->uid = 1;
$comment->name = 'admin';
$comment->mail = 'admin@example.com';
comment_save($comment);
```

You could also do something similar with a Rules component for use with VBO.

Comment: Are you sure it will not invalidate permalinks? Just asking.

Comment: @Molot, the comment cid stays the same so the permalink, e.g `comment/12` will be fine.